# No name 'path' in module 'django.urls'

Tags: python, django, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to set up a Django project using AWS Cloud9 - this is the first time I have used Cloud9 since it moved to AWS, although I had used it for projects previously. I thought I had created the project with no problems, but I am getting a error in urls.py relating to the import of 'path' from django.urls. A warning on the page says:

```
No name 'path' in module 'django.urls'
```

I am using a virtual environment with Python 3.6.8 and Django 2.2.4, but currently I cannot run the project because of this error. On a previous Cloud9 based project, I was using Django 2.1 with Python 3.6 and had no errors with this code.

This is all that is currently in urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Trying to run the project, I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/project/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Comment: Looks like it running an older version of Django?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That was my first thought, but when I try `python -m django --version` it returns 2.2.4.

Comment: Did you activate your venv?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AWS is running django 1.11 or older. `path` was introduced starting django 2.0. check [urls for version 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path)

To check for version run this:

```
python -m django --version
```

Comment: As I say, I am using a virtual environment - I installed the latest version of Django in that, and have checked it since and it is definitely saying that I am running 2.2.4.

Comment: did you configure your webserver to use your python version where you installed your packages?

Comment: I set the AWS environment to run Python 3.6.8.

Comment: Try upgrading to python 3.7

Comment: I have not been able to do that thus far - I tried `sudo yum -y install python37` and got `No package python37 available. Error: Nothing to do`.